# Add ETH to a Ganache account

Tags: ethereum

Is there a way to add ETH to a Ganache account? I am aware that I can typically refresh the accounts by restarting ganache cli, but I'm using the `--db` option, which means the accounts are persistent. Because of this, they've run dry pretty quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't add ether. Your best option is initialize your accounts with very large balances using either `--defaultBalanceEther` for all accounts or with `--account="<PRIVATE_KEY>,<BALANCE>"` for static accounts.

Example with 90,000 ETH

```
ganache-cli --defaultBalanceEther 9000000000000000000000
```

or

```
ganache-cli --account "0x70f1384b24df3d2cdaca7974552ec28f055812ca5e4da7a0ccd0ac0f8a4a9b00,9000000000000000000000"
```

This should at least minimize how frequently you have to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the GUI Interface you can also go to ACCOUNTS & KEYS and set the initial ACCOUNT DEFAULT BALANCE to an absurd value like 100.000 and restart the server.

Now all new accounts should have 100.000ETH each.